# Directed notion of openness

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a notion of openness which only considers certain directions?

e.g. In $\mathbb{R^n}$, given some set of directions (i.e. vectors) $D = \left\{ d_1, \ldots, d_r \right\}$, a set $X$ is $D$-open if given any point $x \in X$, for all $d \in D$ there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $x + t d \in X$ whenever $|t| < \epsilon$.

Informally, moving in a given set of directions $D$, one stays within the set. This wouldn't apply in general topological spaces since it relies on a notion of direction like that in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but I wondered whether it has a name and has been studied?